# typescript interfacer type between two values

Tags: typescript

Hello I'm trying to make a custom error to my project:

```
type Sucess = {
  statusCode:,
  message: [Array<String>] | String,
  type:
}
```

but I had doubts, in statusCode I want to receive numbers between 200 - 299

Comment: You would either make it number or write out all possible values as a numeric literal type.

Comment: hello then i would make number and inside my class error do i manipulate the number?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to ask. Look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types and the other docs maybe.

Comment: basically i need my status code to be between 200 - 299

Comment: Yes, you said that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide all the possible values:

```js
type Sucess = {
    statusCode: 200 | 201 | 202 | 203 | 204 | 205 | 206 | 207 | 208 | 209 | 210 | 211 | 212 | 213 | 214 | 215 | 216 | 217 | 218 | 219 | 220 | 221 | 222 | 223 | 224 | 225 | 226 | 227 | 228 | 229 | 230 | 231 | 232 | 233 | 234 | 235 | 236 | 237 | 238 | 239 | 240 | 241 | 242 | 243 | 244 | 245 | 246 | 247 | 248 | 249 | 250 | 251 | 252 | 253 | 254 | 255 | 256 | 257 | 258 | 259 | 260 | 261 | 262 | 263 | 264 | 265 | 266 | 267 | 268 | 269 | 270 | 271 | 272 | 273 | 274 | 275 | 276 | 277 | 278 | 279 | 280 | 281 | 282 | 283 | 284 | 285 | 286 | 287 | 288 | 289 | 290 | 291 | 292 | 293 | 294 | 295 | 296 | 297 | 298 | 299,
    message: [Array<String>] | String,
}
```